# iPad popover from uitableview, use a disclosure indicator or no?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Asking for your opinions and best practices here about the use (or not) of a disclosure indicator arrow within a UITableView cell where selecting that tableview cell will launch a popover to choose the value of that option in that cell.

On the one hand it makes sense to have the disclosure indicator to let you know selecting that will bring up something else, but on the other hand, the right-pointing arrow doesn't really navigate to a new view like it would on the iPhone.

Ideas, thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tapping the cell does not make a navigation, don't use the disclosure indicator. You can use a custom button designed according to requirement (may be having a down-arrow image,for example) . While tapping this custom button, bring up the pop-over.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.   I gave that some initial thought wasn't entirely comfortable with it, but I think that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple prefers to use a disclosure indicator even if the action if just to show a popover.

An example of this is in the General >'Date & Time' section of the settings app. Turn off set date automatically, then tap on the "Set Date & Time" cell. It has a disclosure indicator but displays a popover when tapped.